# if $x \neq 0$ and $x = \sqrt{4xy - 4y^2}$, then how does expressing $x$ in terms of $y$ mean $x = 2y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have the equation $x=\sqrt{4xy - 4y^2}$, and I know that $x=2y$ when expressed in terms of $y$, but I'm not sure of the process to get there.

I know that 
\begin{align}\sqrt{4xy - 4y^2} &= \sqrt{4y(x-y)}\\
&= 2 \sqrt{y(x-y)} \\
&= 2(xy-y^2)^{\frac12}
\end{align}

but pretty stumped.

Comment: So you have $x = 2\sqrt{(xy - y^2)}$.  Square both sides $x^2 = 4(xy - y^2)$ solve for x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x=\sqrt{4xy - 4y^2}$$
$$x^2=4xy-4y^2$$
$$x^2-4xy+4y^2=0$$
$$(x-2y)^2=0$$
$$x-2y=0$$
$$x=2y$$

Comment: Only for $x\ge0$.

Comment: @egreg: That follows from the first equation, though, yes?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring both sides,

$$x^2=4xy-4y^2$$
$$x^2-4xy+4y^2=0$$
$$(x-2y)^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$x =\sqrt{4xy + 4y^2}$

$x^2 = 4xy - 4y^2$

$x^2 - 4xy + 4y^2 = 0$

$x = \frac{4y \pm \sqrt{16y^2 - 16y^2}}{2}$

$x = \frac{4y \pm \sqrt{0}}{2}$

$x = 2y$